# Проблема при создании нового подключения к LocalDB в VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net

Сегодня пытаюсь создать подключение на новом пк и вылетает такая ошибка. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ну как бы там и написано, в чём может быть проблема

Comment: Кажется, там какое-то дополнение надо поставить, чтобы localdb заработало.

Comment: если sql 2014 - попробуйте так: `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`

Comment: @Ruslan_K спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это частая проблема для тех кто читает примеры которые были написаны до выхода VS 2015. Начиная с VS 2015 Microsoft изменила соглашение для имени MSSQL LocalDB.

Когда я пользуюсь VS 2012  я использую:

```
(localdb)\v11.0
```

Для VS 2015:

```
(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
```

Также можно посмотреть доступные имена для вашей машины нажав на меню вверху *View -> SQL Server Object Explorer*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]